# Cancan it Rolify Ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cancan, rolify

My Ability file has

```
if user.has_role? :admin
  can :manage, :all
else
  can :manage, Company, :id => Company.with_role(:operator, user).pluck(:id)
  ...
end
```

And my Company Controller index has

```
def index
@companies = Company.with_role(:operator, current_user)
```

But when I sign in as a User who operates a company, I cannot access that page. (Even though the Company.with_role(:operator, user) returns a relation in the console!)

Companies have Codes. I am not sure how to write this in cancan:

```
Company.with_role(:operator, user).map{|o| o.codes}
```

But the wiki says if I use a block then authorize_resource will not set the instance variable `@codes`, because it doesn't know which objects belong to the user. So I cannot use:

```
can :manage, Code =>  do |Code|
    user.has_role? :operator, code.company
end
```

I am looking for a solution that will let my CodesController do:

```
def index
if params[:company_id]
  @keywords = Code.where(:company_id => params[:company_id])
end
```

And otherwise show the user all their Codes across all of the Companies they have the `operator` role for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
can :manage, Company do |company|
    user.has_role? :operator, company
end
can :manage, Code do |code|
    user.has_role? :operator, code.company
end
```

If you didn't use block syntax for the can definition you could use load_and_authorize_resource in your CodesController to filter the index to only those that are accessible to the current user.

**Update**
Because this used the block syntax CanCan can't use determine which objects to load with load_resource (since it wants to use SQL syntax). If you can rewrite it to not use a block syntax then you'll be good. If you have to use the role type logic you can add code similar to the following in your index method in your controller:

```
@codes = Code.all.select {|code| can?(:manage, code)}
```

or if you want to bypass the ability in this case for efficiency

```
@codes = Company.with_role(:operator, @current_user).codes
```

Comment: I get undefined method .empty? for nil, nil:class: @codes.empty? in my view. @codes isn't being set by load_and_authorize_resource

Answer (score 0):

```
def index
    if params[:company_id]
      @codes = Company.with_role(:operator, current_user).where(:id => params[:company_id]).map{|o| o.keywords}.flatten
    else
      @codes = Company.with_role(:operator, current_user).map{|operator| operator.keywords}.flatten
    end
  end
```

Comment: @coenwulf this seems to do the trick, but I think I can make it more efficient. Had to post since SO doesn't allow @ in comments